# Xamarin Android Scrollview - Disable Scrolling when Selecting/Typing in Entry?

Tags: android, xamarin, scrollview

I am fairly new to Xamarin, not sure how to solve this problem.
My app is mostly displayed on one NavigationPage.

It is layed out like this:

```
<ContentPage.ToolBarItems>
*Tool Bar items*
</ >
<ScrollView>
---<Grid View>
------<Entry>
------<Label>
------<BoxView>
------*many more*
```

The problem is, whenever I select an Entry, it will scroll the ScrollView to center on the Entry that was selected.
Is there any way to stop this from happening?

[GIF Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG8Td.gif)

Edited question to include answer below
Answer:

This is for Android. You must create a custom renderer, mine is for the ScrollView.
Inside the renderer you must override the OnDescendantInvalidated and RequestChildRectangleOnScreen.

For the OnDescendantInvalidated, i simply commented out the default result.
For the RequestChildRectangleOnScreen, i just returned true.

Code below

```
    public override void OnDescendantInvalidated(Android.Views.View child, Android.Views.View target)
        {
          //  base.OnDescendantInvalidated(child, target);
        }

        public override bool RequestChildRectangleOnScreen(Android.Views.View child, Android.Graphics.Rect rectangle, bool immediate)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: google `Xamarin Android Scrollview Disable Scrolling when focus` shows multiple questions that might be related. Please check those.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did hours of research before asking my question. I did not google those exact key words, but I did try your suggestion. I wasn't able to find my answer online but it led me in the right direction. I modified my question to include the answer.

Comment: Great!  When you figure out answer to your own question, instead of editing question, please add "Your Answer" below. This makes it more obvious that the question has an answer.